# Why does my ajax in wordpress does not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I wrote a hello world plugin.

I am following now https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins to add some ajax functionality to my plugin.

The code that works:

```
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); // Write our JS below here

function my_action_javascript() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'whatever': 1234
        };

        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
    </script> <?php
}

<?php 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

This code gives me a pop up(1244) as expected but I do not want it to run automatically but when I click a button.
For that reason I removed `add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); // Write our JS below here`
and changed a bit the code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function aaa(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'whatever': 1234
        };

        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
    }
    </script> <?php
```

and I added a code on the function where I print hello world in the plugin:

```
    ?>
<button onclick="aaa()"> aaa</button>
<?
```

I hit the button and it returns:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function aaa(){
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
}
</script>1244
```

So 1244 is still there but it prints also the whole javascript code..
what am I missing?

Isn't this the correct way to trigger the ajax in wordpress?

How else could I do it with a button without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand what you're asking: you want a pop-up with 1244 to appear when you press a button.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="aaa()">Do Something</button>
```

**JavaScript**

First we'll need to update your JS to only fire the aaa() function on click, so we can scrap all the stuff about the document's ready state. We're also using a different way of accessing the admin-ajax.php file, but more on that in the PHP script. The JavaScript should be placed in a file rather than printed directly on the page.

```
// Function is called on button click
function aaa() {
   var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': 1234
    };
    // Script has been localized and can now use this object
    jQuery.post(my_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
}
```

**PHP**

Here, instead of printing the JS directly in the footer, this is how you'll load it. You can also localize it so it can access admin-ajax.php. [Here is documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/) on the `plugins_url()` function.

```
function my_javascript() {
    //Add your script to be loaded in the footer
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'my-script', // Handle of your script
        plugins_url('/path/to/script.js', 'my-plugin'), //URL to your JS file
        array('jquery'), //Dependencies
        '', // Version number
        true // Place in footer
    );
    //Localize it so it can use AJAX
    wp_localize_script(
        'my-script', //Handle of your script
        'my_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') )
    );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_javascript'); //Enqueue styles for backend


function my_action() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

    wp_die($whatever); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );//Works for logged-in users
```

Comment: Thanks. in function my_javascript() { i had to remove ); and add ; on the line before right after admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ) ) in order to run. however when i click on the button nothing happens. After inspecting in chrome i see "Uncaught ReferenceError: aaa is not defined. I replaced plugins_url('/path/to/script.js', 'my-plugin') with plugins_url('hello-world.js', 'hello-world') but still same error.. edited: worked with plugins_url( 'hello-world.js', __FILE__ ) and as I saied before removing the " ) " edit2: i am trying to write __ FILE __ without spaces but it only bolds the "FILE"

Comment: At the top of a JS file, I'll sometimes write `console.info('my_script.js has loaded');` to ensure that the file was found successfully and that I didn't mess up the URL to my JS file. Can you try that to check?